# why do I am getting random output and more output than accepted?

Tags: c++14

### Question

After solving programming problems for years, Chef has become lazy and decided to get a better physique by doing some weight lifting exercises.

On any regular day, Chef does N exercises at times A1, A2,…, AN (in minutes, all distinct), and each exercise provides a tension of B1, B2,…, BN units. In the period between two consecutive exercises, his muscles relax R units of tension per minute.

More formally, Chef's tension is described by a number x. Before any workouts, x=0. When he does a workout at time Ai, the tension x instantly increases by Bi. Between workouts, the number x decreases by R units per minute maximized with 0.

Considering the time of exercise and hence tension to be negligible, find the maximum tension he will be feeling in his muscles during the entire period of his workout.

### Input:

First line will contain T, the number of test cases. Then the test cases follow.
Each test case contains 3 lines of input.
The first line will contain 2 space-separated integers N, R, the number of timestamps at which Chef performs his exercise, and units of tension relaxed per minute.
The second line contains N space-separated integers A1, A2,…, AN.
The third line contains N space-separated integers B1, B2,…, BN.
Output:
For each test case, output in a single line the maximum amount of tension Chef will have in his muscles.

### Constraints

1≤T≤10

1≤N≤5⋅10^4

1≤R,B[i]≤10^5

1≤A[i]≤10^9

A[i]−1<A[i], for all 2≤i≤N

### Sample Input:

3

1 2

10

10

2 2

10 11

10 10

3 1

1 2 3

1 2 3

### Sample Output:

10

18

4

### my output

22090

-44170

1

987400726

-1974801434

1

1

10960

-10956

### My implementation

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int before(int p,int q){
        int x,c;
        int a[p];
        int b[p];
        for(int j=0;j<p;j++){
            cin>>a[j];
        }
        for(int h=0;h<p;h++){
            cin>>b[h];
        }
        for(int k=0;k<p;k++){
            x += b[k];
            c = a[k+1]-a[k];
            c *=q;
            x -=c;
            
            
        }
        return x;
         
}

int main() {
     int t;
     cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        int n,r;
        cin>>n>>r;
       int d = before(n,r);
       cout<<d<<endl;
    }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `x` is not initialized so you don't know what value it starts with. Your code has other issues but it's "competitive programming" and nobody in that community cares if you write garbage.

Comment: ...and `a[k+1]` reads past the end of the array on the last loop iteration.